# Write multiple data frames to S3 simultaneously

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-s3

I have a requirement such that I have to create multiple intermediate data frames which I need to write to different directories.

```
//this is just a pseudocode
//df is a master data frame
df1 = df.select(some columns)
df2 = df.select(some columns)
df3 = df.select(some columns)
df4 = df.select(some columns)

df1.write(dir1)
df2.write(dir2)
df3.write(dir3)
df4.write(dir4)
```

I have tried two options -

1. create 4 separate job and spawn all 4 jobs simultaneously using Oozie fork-join but the flip side here is that all 4 jobs reading same data, and
2. create 1 job and write to 4 directories after transformations, here the flip side is jobs which use output data of df1 will have to wait until the writing of all 4 df's gets completed.

Also, each job or individual writing to S3 spends 70-75% of the total time in IO.

Is there any other way which I can use or try ?

Comment: Have you tried to call `dfx.write(dirx)` each in separate thread?

Comment: Anyway, in case when you reuse `df` multiple times (as in your example) be aware that whatever was done with `df` prior to `select` (including reading from storage) will be done multiple times unless you [persist](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-caching.html) it.